# How to run a file that's in a different directory in repl.it?

Tags: python, replit

I know repl starts at the base directory and looks for main.py but I have it inside a src folder. Is there a way I can run that when pressing the "run" button?

I have tried bringing the main.py outside the src folder and it works (with a little rewrite of the imports) but I feel like there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repl.it, by default, always run `/main.ext` (`.ext` determined by the programming language) when you press on the run button. If you have the main file in a non-root directory or with a different file name, repl.it supports a configuration file to set a different command for the run button.

If your `main.py` file is at `src/main.py`, first create a new file with the name `.replit` (saved to the root of the repl) then type the following in the file:

```yaml
language = "python3"
run = "python src/main.py"
```

This will tell repl.it to run the command `python src/main.py` instead of `python main.py` (the default) when you press the run button.

If you also need the cwd to change to `src/`, you can add it to the `.replit` file as well:

```yaml
language = "python3"
run = "cd src && python main.py"
```